# digest error on sucess() over then() angularjs with typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise, angular-services, angularjs-digest

I created a angular js service in typescript to post a file , when it is successful I just used `alert()` to notify the user.

```
uploadFileToUrl = (file, uploadUrl) =>  {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    this.$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
    .success(() => {
        alert("file uploaded");
    })
    .error(() => {
        alert("some error occured.");
    });
}
```

I can debug the code and verify the call is indeed successful, but when call returns, it shows success and then theres a **digest error** but if I just return a promise from service and in controller use `then()` , it works fine.

```
uploadFileToUrl = (file, uploadUrl) => {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    return this.$http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    })
}
```

I wanted to know what is the problem with `success()` and if `then()` should always be preferred over `success()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the promise mechanism in angular is provided by `$q`.

Few weeks ago, I had seen `promise.success()` and `promise.error()` deprecated. Both don't appear in the documentation anymore.

So, I'd suggest you to avoid using the `success()` and `error()` and use `then(successFunction, errorFunction);` instead.

[Documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q/#the-promise-api)

**Edit**

After having checked the source code, I can ensure you the `.success` and `.error` don't exist anymore into the latest angular source code

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L3